# When to use Angular JS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have worked with knockout JS , Angular JS but I am still not sure when I need to use Angular JS in practical scenarios of project.

I am using Angular with MVC but I am not sure do I need to use Angular with my input forms.

If I user Angular with MVC then I need to put validation by creating `ng-model`  in my HTML.

In other way when I use Jquery and bind my MVC view with

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
```

This provide me validation based on my property class data-annotation attributes.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are asking when to use AngularJS (as it appear from first statement), it is a broad and opinion based question. If you are asking for help solving a specific problem (as it appear from later part) I suggest you modify your question and make it specific.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Angular.JS with MVC. The choice depends on the factors that what application you are building on. If the web app you are making dont need a JS dont put burden of it. I will try to put some points which might help you.

- Application with very frequent to & fro data flow.
- Sort of E-Commerce requirement or you need strong filters with search.
- You need to use DOM.
- Working on MVC, Angular helps in keeping things binded together.

I hope it helps.

Comment: @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
You can use this, but then its better to use a stable framework.